# How do I use awk to prepend a directory to a list of files in a variable?

Tags: bash, awk

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES='a.txt
b.txt
c.txt'
OUT_FILES=$(awk -F ' ' \$0=\"foo/bar/\"\$0 <(echo ${FILES}))

echo ${OUT_FILES}
```

In the above script, I expect a list of files in `${OUT_FILES}` as  `foo/bar/a.txt foo/bar/b.txt foo/bar/c.txt`, but the output is `foo/bar/a.txt b.txt c.txt`. Later on, the `${OUT_FILES}` list is provided to another command with `xargs`. What is wrong with the awk expression that results in only prepending the path to the first element of the list?

Comment: your input is not 3 lines long but just one line.  quote the "${FILES}".

Comment: Why don't you put the awk script in single quotes, instead of escaping all the special characters? `'$0 = "foo/bar/" $0'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quotes are missing, also will be cleaner this way.

```
$ awk '{print "foo/bar/" $0}' <<< "$FILES"
foo/bar/a.txt
foo/bar/b.txt
foo/bar/c.txt
```

perhaps easier with `sed`

```
$ sed 's_^_foo/bar/_' <<< "$FILES"
foo/bar/a.txt
foo/bar/b.txt
foo/bar/c.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an array would be a much much better way to store the filenames:

```
dirname="/tmp/foo"
files=( a.txt b.txt c.txt )
out_files=( "${files[@]/#/$dirname/}" )
```

Let's see what those arrays now contain:

```
$ declare -p files out_files dirname
declare -a files='([0]="a.txt" [1]="b.txt" [2]="c.txt")'
declare -a out_files='([0]="/tmp/foo/a.txt" [1]="/tmp/foo/b.txt" [2]="/tmp/foo/c.txt")'
```

`"${files[@]/#/$dirname/}"` is a fairly tricky [parameter  expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

- `${parameter/pattern/string}` replaces the first occurrance of *pattern* with the given *string*

  - if *pattern* starts with `#`, then the match will be anchored to the beginning of the value of *$parameter*
  - so I'm matching the *empty string* at the start of the value, and replacing that *empty string* with the value of $dirname and a literal slash
- if *parameter* is an array expansion, then the pattern replacing will occur for each element of the array.

Another point to note, don't use ALLCAPS_VARNAMES: it's too easy to over-write crucial shell variables (like $PATH).